# Object pronouns in subject position?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I found this [old question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/121976/usage-of-in-spite-of) in SE-ELL, particularly the comments on the last (Hector von's) answer, and it stirred my curiosity about the usage of object pronouns in subject position.

I believe that in colloquial English, sentences like these can be used:

*Us cartographers can map the world / Me and Jeremy are going to the supermarket*

But I would like to focus on the following examples:

1. In spite of his being a mere boy, he offered to fight the giant
2. In spite of him being a mere boy, he offered to fight the giant
3. In spite of he being a mere boy, he offered to fight the giant

And

1. Our having to undergo this disgrace is a pity
2. Us having to undergo this disgrace is a pity
3. We having to undergo this disgrace is a pity

For both examples, I would say that (1) is the correct and recommended form, (2) is an accepted colloquialism and (3) is incorrect, but I cannot explain why and especially why (2) must be chosen over (3).

Comment: I think the duplicate addresses usage rather well but you could edit if you're asking about a part that's not covered in the answers.

Comment: This seems to be asked daily now, but I don't know why: [0](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/592812), [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/532617), [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/516423), [3](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/475630), [4](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/434787), [5](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/96742), [6](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/253181), [7](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/488017), [8](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/488640), [9](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/426234), [10](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/94272).

Comment: In particular, [this answer from yesterday](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/592820) *should* have within it the answers to all your puzzles. If you cannot find them there, please just say so.

Comment: I wonder if it's exam time somewhere.